# how to read files of a directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

```
FM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
directoryContents = [FM contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/myComputer/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/CD88649C-E545-4E10-84DF-F4E5D829641B/Documents" error:NULL];
```

but it gives me object not the path for object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to read files stored in directory. By using:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil]
```

It returns the file or folder name stored at that location. Then we can again append these names in a string to read these files.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
for (NSString *tString in dirContents) 
{
  //Do some stuff here  
}
```

See this Post [Get directory contents in date modified order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523793/get-directory-contents-in-date-modified-order/3358929#3358929)

Answer (score 0):

I really not understand the hardcoded string for the bundle path use below for getting the bundle path

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

your code must be similar with below.

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
```