# How to detect whether a file is modified in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, file, checksum

**How to detect whether a file is modified in iOS?**

I don't mean the real-time monitoring, because while the application is gone, it won't detect anymore.

I've checked the attributes of the file, and couldn't find the satisfied one.(Did I miss something?)

There maybe some check-sum generating solutions, but they will require much time.
(*Is there any cheap check-sum generating algorithm?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which attributes did you check? With `fstat()`, you should be able to compare the [`st_mtime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) attribute of a file with a previously stored value.

Comment: Is it the same as the NSFileModificationDate?

Comment: It could be the same, but apparently `stat` works much faster. See the following SO answer that demonstrates the use of `stat` to get the modification date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1999553/19410

Comment: It's not made clear, but that sample code looks like an Objective C category that extends `NSDate` (if you're interested in that detail).

Comment: Ah, now I know why that was bothering me. I think if you try to send an app to Apple for approval, which contains a category that extends a class in an Apple API (like `NSDate`), then said app will be rejected. So I would use that code to learn `stat`, and then modify it into a method in a "local", non-Apple helper class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/stat.2.html)), to get the modification time of the file.  You could then compare it against your stored value:

```
struct stat sb;
if (stat("/path/to/file", &sb) == 0)
{
    ... compare sb.st_mtimespec with stored value

}
else
{
    ... report error
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108953/iphone-how-do-you-find-the-creation-date-of-a-file) is pretty close to yours.

Comment: Is it the same as the NSFileModificationDate?