# How to list out Recently Opened documents in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocument

I have listed out all the documents in NSDocument Directory and im able to get the documents that are recently modified using :

```
NSMutableArray* filesAndProperties = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[filesArray count]];
for(NSString* file in filesArray) {
    NSString* filePath = [iMgr.documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSDictionary* properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath
                                error:&error];
    NSDate* modDate = [properties objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

    if(error == nil)
    {
        [filesAndProperties addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       file, @"path",
                                       modDate, @"lastModDate",
                                       nil]];                 
    }
}
```

by fallowing :
[Get directory contents in date modified order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523793/get-directory-contents-in-date-modified-order)

Now how can i list out the documents that have been opened and viewed by the user without any editing or modifications  ?

Comment: That class only provides creation and modification dates, not access dates, so it looks like you can't.

Comment: Ok is there any other way  ? or work around to do this ?